# installing java in linux issues

Tags: linux

Im trying to install Java in install but for some reason its not working.

I tried the same way as mentioned in this website-http://www.java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml#enable

I see Java installed in my desktop when I try this command,

premvidya@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ls
jre1.6.0_31  jre-6u31-linux-i586(2).bin  jre-6u31-linux-i586.bin

but when I try java - version, I get the following error,

premvidya@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ java -version
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * gij-4.3
 * java-gcj-compat-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
 * cacao
 * gij-4.2
 * jamvm
 * kaffe
Try: sudo apt-get install 
bash: java: command not found

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to manually install java? There is a repository for this, and it's all managed for you. Uninstall whatever you have put on your system manually and install it via command line.

apt-get cache search java
apt-get cache search jdk

*or*
start Ubuntu Software Center -> search for java.

Once installed via apt-get, the new java commands will be available immediately in your PATH, so long as you haven't removed anything...

Comment: I get this error with the command you gave me,  premvidya@ubuntu:~$ apt-get cache search java apt-get cache search jdk
E: Invalid operation cache..How do I go to the Ubuntu software center..I new to Linux

Comment: Here is my output result,premvidya@ubuntu:~$ apt-cache search java6
premvidya@ubuntu:~$ apt-cache search java
gdb - The GNU Debugger
libdbus-1-3 - simple interprocess messaging system
dbus - simple interprocess messaging system
libgtksourceview-common - common files for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget
openoffice.org-core - full-featured office productivity suite -- arch-dependent files
brltty - Access software for a blind person using a braille display
libgtksourceview2.0-common - common files for the GTK+ syntax highlighting widget

Comment: sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get upgrade ; clear ; echo "now type apt-cache search java"

Comment: I think your package repos are very out of date if all apt-cache search java6 produced was what you posted. You might want to go to System -> preferences -> software sources and check things out.

Comment: sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk openjdk-6-jre

Answer (score 1):

[@user1050619](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1050619/user1050619)

Hi user1050619,
I have come across the solution which will work on any version of Ubuntu definitely keeping other java versions intact.

I have used standalone installation of Java.

For this, please download tar.gz version of Java from 
[Oracle website.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

1. Suppose, your jdk installation tar file at location `/home/don/`
2. don@ubuntu ~ $ `tar zxf jdk-7u45-linux-i586.tar.gz`
3. don@ubuntu ~ $ `sudo bash`

   [sudo] password for don:
4. ubuntu ~ # `mv /home/don/jdk1.7.0_45/ /usr/lib/jvm/`
5. ubuntu ~ # `cd /usr/lib/jvm/`
6. ubuntu jvm # `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java 3`
7. ubuntu jvm # `update-alternatives --config java`

> ```
>  Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status  
> ------------------------------------------------------------  
> * 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode  
>   1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode  
>   2            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java               3         manual mode  
> Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
> update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode
> ```

8. ubuntu jvm # `java -version`
   java version "1.7.0_45"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
   Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

and you are done here without any hassles.

Happy programming !!

Answer (score 0):

it should be "apt-cache search java6" or just "apt-cache search java".  It'll give you a list of all the package related to java.  If you want to install sun's java then you download the java-**.bin file like you did and then run "sudo /bin/sh jre-6u31-linux-i586.bin"  That'll run the installer from the sun java you downloaded and begin to install.  Answer the question and install the package.